# Install plugin cordova

Tags: javascript, android, gps, cordova-plugins

I have to develop an app that check if gps is enabled or disabled. If gps is disabled, I have to send users on device's settings.

I find [this](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.dataforpeople.plugins.gpssettings/%22this%22) plugin to do that.

So, I installed the plugin using node.js using command line (cordova plugin add com.dataforpeople.plugins.gpssettings).

I use this code in javascript file to go to device's settings :

```
var gpsDetect = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/gpsDetectionPlugin');
phonegapReady().then(function () {
    gpsDetect.checkGPS(onSuccess, onError);
});
```

but in the logcat i have this error:

> 07-22 15:36:59.555: E/Web Console(2230): Uncaught module
>   cordova/plugin/gpsDetectionPlugin not found at
>   file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:59

Anyone know how can I fix this problem?